# Laravel model return Undefined property::$attribute

Tags: laravel, model

I have model Post with attributes: `id, content, image, publish_date`.
In the Post model I can get all attributes but image when using `$this->$attr` it shows me Undefined property when calling $this->image. I don't know why. But when I call in the `Controller: Post::find(1)->image`, it works fine.
Can anyone help me pls?

Comment: is there any errors ?

Comment: It shows me Undefined property when calling $this->image. But $this->id, $this->content,..all work OK.

Comment: Please show the code.

Comment: public function getImageAttribute()
{
       dd($this->image);
}
I have just dd() for test but it returns undefined. Maybe cause the accessor?

Answer (score 15):

Since you're using an [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor), try to do this:

```
public function getImageAttribute($value)
{
    dd($value);
}
```

Comment: OMG. it's my careless. It works nice. Thanks for helping me twice ^^

Answer (score 7):

This was the first link that showed up in my google search, so I am posting the solution I found here as well, for anyone else running into the same issue.

In relation to the question above, I would have had to use `$this->attributes['image']`, specifically for accessing.